# How to handle touch events and gesture events on screen

Tags: java, android

i want to set on touch listener and use on touch right

in On Create Method i set On Touch Listener for Main Layout

```
mainActivityLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

XML File:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

then override onTouchEvent, but not working

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "On Touch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (event.getAction() == *TouchRight*)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Touch Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

how i can handle gesture events ?

Comment: That means you are setting touch listener on root layout?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed yes, i want to set for all area of screen

Comment: I have updated my answer add those xml attributes to your main parent layout That will work for you

Comment: you need to check what is this reference holding mainActivityLayout. Weather that is the holding the reference of your linear layout which you just shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code sample

```
float initialX, initialY;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

int action = event.getActionMasked();

switch (action) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialX = event.getX();
        initialY = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.d(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalX = event.getX();
        float finalY = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");

        if (initialX < finalX) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialX > finalX) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialY < finalY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialY > finalY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        Log.d(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        Log.d(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
        break;
}

return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Hope that answer the question
EDIT
For your parent layout to work add below code to your parent layout like Relative layout

```
     android:clickable="true"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: on Touch Event never call!and log cat is empty !

Comment: in your code, you are showing toast was that working for you?

Comment: no , in my code and your code OnTouchEvent never call

Comment: this is happening because you are not setting the setOnTouchListener() to any view. First set the this listener to any view then it will working fine

Comment: then you must be missing something i have checked it. it is working

Comment: one more thing please verify you are setting touch listener to the right parent and that parent has those attributes as I mentioned